# How to read the request body in reactor-netty server?

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

How to read the request body in reactor-netty server?
**I want to get the request body to determine the content of the response, but I can't find an example of that in the sample code.**

### My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Consumer<ByteBuf> onSuccess = (ByteBuf request) -> {
            System.out.println("onSuccess: Request received!");
        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        };
        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");

        };
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create().handle(new BiFunction<HttpServerRequest, HttpServerResponse, Publisher<Void>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<Void> apply(HttpServerRequest httpServerRequest, HttpServerResponse httpServerResponse) {
                        Mono<byte[]> mono = httpServerRequest.receive()
                                .aggregate()
                                .asByteArray()
                                .doOnNext(new Consumer<byte[]>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void accept(byte[] bytes) {
                                        System.out.println(1);
                                    }
                                })
                                .doOnError(onError)
                                .doOnTerminate(onCompletion)
                                .flatMap(bytes -> {
                                    return Mono.just(bytes);
                                });
                        mono.block();
                        // I want to get http body;

                        return httpServerResponse.sendString(Mono.just("Hello world"));
                    }
                }).host("localhost")
                        .port(45441)
                        .bindNow();
        System.in.read();
    }
```

Exception

> block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2

Invoker

> curl http://127.0.0.1:45441/test1/test -d "12312321312" -i  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -vvv

pom

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue -->
        <!--    <dependency>-->
        <!--        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>-->
        <!--        <artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>-->
        <!--        <version>4.1.66.Final</version>-->
        <!--        <classifier>osx-x86_64</classifier>-->
        <!--    </dependency>-->

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>4.1.66.Final</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport -->
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.10</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

### Thank you for you answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Reactor Netty you have to do the opposite logic: Send these bytes when you receive those bytes. You should never block in the event loop. The example above can be rewritten like the one below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    };
    Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
        System.out.println("Message Completed");
    };
    DisposableServer server =
            HttpServer.create()
                    .handle((req, res) ->
                            res.sendByteArray(req.receive()
                                    .aggregate()
                                    .asByteArray()
                                    .doOnNext(bytes -> System.out.println(1))
                                    .doOnError(onError)
                                    .doOnTerminate(onCompletion)
                                    .flatMap(Mono::just)))
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port(45441)
                    .bindNow();

    server.onDispose()
            .block();
}
```

There are more examples in the [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_routing_http)